# {{selected}} no longer get/display autocomplete value (more input tags on page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autofill

The operation was type in the input field, an array of autofill options would '*recommend*' you could choose one, and then the `{{selected}}` area would populate immediately with the choice.

I have added a simple contact form on the page in the form of a pop-up modal and *now* the `{{selected}}` is not updating with choice from autofill. *Instead* what it does is just populates with the exact text typed in the autofill input field, and just keeps that. The autofill itself is working still, but no longer updates dynamic selected template area when item chosen.

I am suspecting it's this: `iElement.trigger('input');` But as mentioned below I have tried swapping from global input tag to `input#specific` any other ideas to call?

```
iElement.trigger('input#specific');
```

**JS:**

```
function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Sample, Sample, Sample, Blah, Blah, Nicholas, Becky, Apples, Oranges, You get the idea"];
}
angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```

**Mark-up:**

```
<div ng-app='MyModule' id="search">
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl' class="main_contain">
            <div class="start">I came here looking for a <span class="blank">{{selected}}</span></div><br>
        <br>    
        <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected" id="fill" placeholder="Start typing...">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/) is how it was originally working. Though, clearly I cannot use the global `input` tag.

How can I specify differently using angular `iElement.trigger` specifying `#id` is clearly not working. Attribute?

I have also tried passing as a variable with no avail.

```
var input = $("input#fill").val();
```

Comment: is there anymore code that should be posted? looks incomplete.

Comment: Just added the mark-up